# Angular Custom Pipe: SafeValue must use [property]=binding

Tags: angular, html-sanitizing, angular2-custom-pipes

This is my CustomPipe Code:

Here , text is a big chunk of string. And `searchColl` is the collection of words which needs to be highlighted in it.

This is working well and highlighting all the words in the text, but it appends `"SafeValue must use [property]=binding"` on the rendered text like this:

[image: Outcome of SafeValue]

```js
transformAddress(text: any, searchColl) {
    searchColl.forEach(search => {
        if (search !== undefined && search !== null) {
            search = search.toString().replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
          }
          text += '';
          var tempText =  this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(search ? text.replace(new RegExp(`(${search})`, 'gi'),
            '<span style="background-color: blue">' + `$1` + '</span>') : text);
          text = tempText; // After 1st word from collection is highlighted search this becomes the new input.
    });

     return   this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text);
    
}
```

This is how I am using it in my component code:

```js
var retPipeData = this.highlightPipe.transformAddress(source,itemsToSearch);
console.log('DataFromPipe', retPipeData);
// var massagedData = retPipeData.toString().replace('SafeValue must use [property]=binding:','');
// var massagedHTML = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML,this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(massagedData));
// console.log('massagedDataAfterreplace', massagedData);
// console.log('massagedHTML', massagedHTML);

this.tab1Response = retPipeData;
```

I was also trying to remove this string from the string received from Pipe but that is also not working ( see commented code above).

Also, I even tried:

```
this._sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML,this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text))
```

But no success.

Can someone please point out what iam doing wrong.

Comment: what was the source value on here   
var retPipeData = this.highlightPipe.transformAddress(source,itemsToSearch);

Comment: try not use "var" else "let" or "const"